# Links not working through jQuery. Need to link to a new page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs

It utilizes jQuery to show and hide the different "tabs", but they want to link to a different page in the tabs and I can't get it to work.

I tried searching for a solution, but maybe I am not asking/searching for the correct terms or something.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below jQuery code:

```js
$("#tabs li a").click(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('href'),"_self");
});
```

and remove on hover `$(this).click();` in your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nav` element overlaps the `div` before it.
Try to remove `postion:relative;` on the element.